# Run all shell scripts in folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have many `.sh` scripts in a single folder and would like to run them one after another. A single script can be executed as:

```
bash wget-some_long_number.sh -H
```

Assume my directory is `/dat/dat1/files`

How can I run `bash wget-some_long_number.sh -H` one after another?

I understand something in these lines should work:

`for i in *.sh;...do ....; done`

Comment: just put the command after `do`, your loop variable will be the filename without extension.  Obviously, this will be missing any kind of error handling.  What happens if one of the scripts fail?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use this:

```
for f in *.sh; do
  bash "$f" 
done
```

If you want to stop the whole execution when a script fails:

```
for f in *.sh; do
  bash "$f" || break  # execute successfully or break
  # Or more explicitly: if this execution fails, then stop the `for`:
  # if ! bash "$f"; then break; fi
done
```

And to preserve the exit code of the failed script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e  # exit on error
for f in *.sh; do
  bash "$f"
done
```

Comment: @Kirril can you explain what the `break` does? I do not want the job to stop at any time. Skip any failed script and continue to the next.

Comment: `break` stops the loop. Just omit `|| break`.

Comment: Great! Thanks @Kirill Bulygin

Comment: why `-H`? ..to "Enable !  style history substitution" from `man bash`, or is it a conditional not listed in man bash?

Comment: @alchemy This is an option not of `bash` but rather of the command used in the original question (`wget-some_long_number.sh -H`).

Comment: @KirillBulygin using the break isnt really a good idea since it will just break the loop without transfering the information about the error ... if you use something like this in your CI/CD pipelines for instance, they will pass cuz no erro code was returned

Comment: @VespaQQ Agree. For the original answer, I assumed that OP wanted to run the loop interactively. I've updated the answer.

Comment: And which order does it use to execute the files?

Comment: @august0490 Alphabetical (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#:~:text=replaced%20with%20an%20alphabetically%20sorted%20list%20of%20filenames%20matching%20the%20pattern). You can run `printf '%s\n' *.sh` to see the exact order for your files.

Answer (score 37):

There is a much simpler way, you can use the `run-parts` command which will execute all scripts in the folder:

```sh
run-parts /path/to/folder
```

Comment: It won't execute all scripts. From `man run-parts` on Debian: `... the names must consist entirely of ASCII upper- and lower-case letters, ASCII digits, ASCII underscores, and ASCII minus-hyphens` (note that `.sh` or `.` is not allowed), `Other files and  directories are silently ignored`. `run-parts` is primarily used by `cron` and is not reliable for manual usage.

Comment: @KirillBulygin, you can use option like : --regex to avoid initial naming constraint.

Comment: Then the approach becomes not that simple, doesn't it?

Comment: Although in cases with quite special naming it's simpler indeed than regex matching in bash.

Comment: Another problem is that run-parts won't ever return a non-zero error code, even if a script exits with an error, so you lose any way to check for errors.

Comment: `run-parts` was designed for a specific purpose; if you are trying to use it for something sufficiently different, it will not be a very good solution. And of course if you are not on a Debian-based platform, this particular tool doesn't exist there. `printf '%s\n' ./* | sh` does much the same thing anyway.

Comment: I didn't know about this command and now I love it! thanks for share

Comment: You know, we learn every day from others, l'm happy to have read your comment, know im sure to reach the goal of enjoying at least one person in this world. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem where I couldn't use loops and run-parts works with cron.

#### Answer:

```
foo () {
    bash -H $1 
    #echo $1
    #cat $1
}
cd /dat/dat1/files #change directory
export -f foo #export foo
parallel foo ::: *.sh #equivalent to putting a & in between each script
```

You use GNU parallel, this executes everything in the directory, with the added buff of it happening at a lot faster rate. Not to mention it isn't just with script execution, you could put any command in the function and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

The following does weird things, as it removes the `./` prefix given by `find`, and following this all files are running in the shell. That is playing with fire (...)

```
find . | xargs cut -c2-
```