# Run "N" Shell Scripts in Folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, automation

I have a working piece of code to run all scripts in a directory:
[Run all shell scripts in folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079143/run-all-shell-scripts-in-folder)

```
for f in *.sh; do \
bash "$f" -H || break
done
```

I also have code to run a sequence of .sh scripts:

```
for f in {1..3}madeupname.sh; do \
bash "$f" -H || break
done
```

Now instead of running all .sh scripts or a range of .sh scripts, I want to run "N" number of .sh scripts where N is an arbitrary number say 3 .sh scripts for example.

The order in which N files are run is not important to me.

Comment: But why? What are you actually trying to achieve? Why not just list the three files you want to run? What is the background of this question?

Comment: Because the order of the files does not matter and I do not want to manually retype each set of files. I want to just have it run 30 files every 24 hours for example.

Comment: The .sh scripts are self deleting after they finish running so if I say execute script {1..3} they will be deleted after.

Comment: @Bernhard The files which get run are arbitrary, I just don't want to submit them all at once.

Comment: Look at `GNU shuf`... https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html#shuf-invocation

Comment: @Mark Setchell I am not sure how this applies? Maybe I missed something you had in mind.

Comment: are the process run in a sequence or in parallel. Seems it sequential so maybe you just have to keep a count of number of process run and to break when it's 3

Comment: @Nahuel Fouilleul they are in serial but as soon as the script is executed the .sh file is removed from directory negating the need to track which files are run.

Comment: I maybe mis-understood the question. I thought you wanted some degree of randomness about which 3 you choose, but I guess the first 3 is fine. Ignore me.

Comment: @Mark Setchell either way could be random or first 3 the order is not an issue in this application, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find` the scripts, get the `head`, then execute with `xargs`.

```
find . -name '*.sh' | head -n 10 | xargs -n1 sh
```

You can run the scripts in parallel with `xargs` with a simple `-P0` option. You can script the `xargs` with some `xargs sh -c 'bash "$@" -H || exit 125' --` to make `xargs` exit with nonzero status or immediately after any of the scripts fail to run or something.

If you feel like unfamiliar with `xargs`, just do a simple `while read` loop:

```
find . -name '*.sh' | head -n 10 | 
while IFS= read -r script; do
    bash "$script" -H || break
done
```

And in parallel you have to get out of the pipe subshell:

```
while IFS= read -r script; do
    bash "$script" -H || break &
done < <(
     find . -name '*.sh' | head -n 10
)
wait # for all the childs
```

or wait for childs in the subshell itself:

```
find . -name '*.sh' | head -n 10 |
{
    while IFS= read -r script; do
        bash "$script" -H || break &
    done
    wait
}
```

Comment: Hi Kamil, this ended up working, one more thing... is it possible to add a sleep 5 command in the xargs statement? I ended up using "find . -name '*.sh' | head -n 10 | xargs -n1 sh"

Comment: It looks easier to add the sleep to the submission scripts instead of xargs!

Comment: sure, you can do anything, but the quoting get's used to. You run a command inside xargs and pass arguments to it, and you can run shell. So `xargs -n1 sh -c 'sh "$@" ; sleep 1' --` will work as expected. The `"$@"` is expanded inside sh inside xargs to the arguments. Add `-t` to `xargs` to observe and add `-x` to `sh` to debug, ex. `xargs -t -n1 sh -x -c ' sh "$@" ; sleep 1' --`

Comment: Very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

From comments, keeping a count of process run

```
count=0
for f in *.sh; do
    bash "$f" -H || break
    ((++count>=3)) && break
done
```

Comment: trying this now

Comment: Tried this verbatim, it is still running all files in the folder. Not sure why?

Comment: is there another loop around otherwise there's no reason, you may add `echo "$count process launched"` to trace

Comment: no other loops, I am going to type this into the shell manually and see.

Comment: What is telling the counter to count up?

Comment: the `++` before is the pre increment, otherwise if it's clearer could be decomposed `((count+=1)); ((count>=3)) && break`. Note that the double parenthesis is for bash arithmetic expression, and are important whereas single parenthese is for a sub shell call.

Comment: trying it again now

Comment: It is still submitting all of the files... no idea why