# How to include and run all python scrips in single wrapper script

Tags: python, shell, unix, websphere

I have some 12 python scripts and i execute them individually
Now I want to include those 12 scripts in single shell wrappper and wants to run this wrapper which can execute all 12 at a time.
i have tried the below simple shell but unable to execute it

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/<user>/serverlist.py
/home/<user>/cluster.py
/home/<user>/listApps.py

`
[root@bin]# ./wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f /home/Devop/wrapper.py
WASX7209I: Connected to process "server1" on node localhostNode02 using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: UnManagedProcess
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "/home/Devop/wrapper.py"; exception information: com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython:
Traceback (innermost last):
  (no code object) at line 0
  File "<string>", line 3
    sh "./home/Devop/listApps.py" 
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
I  am getting this syntax error
```

Comment: "Unable" how? If the paths are correct, this script should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079143/run-all-shell-scripts-in-folder (easy hint: replace `bash` with `python3` or whatever your Python interpreter is called, or just omit it if the scripts have a valid shebang and execute permissions).

Comment: bash is the correct interpreter to have in the #!, but you need to put the whole wsadmin command each time and then exec the wrapper in bash, not wsadmin. So `./wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f /home/<user>/serverlist.py` and so on. You run that script in the shell as ./wrapper.sh. Otherwise you have to use `execfile` in your single wsadmin script to exec the others, see https://github.com/WASdev/sample.daytrader7/blob/358af79fcaa6e1c437312fd58e07241d3164dd1b/scripts/daytrader_SILENT_singleServer.py#L33

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 /home/<user>/serverlist.py #or just python
python3 /home/<user>/cluster.py
python3 /home/<user>/listApps.py
```

Comment: Note that if these scripts are WebSphere wsadmin scripts, you have to run them with wsadmin.sh and the -f parameter, since they need the context of an active WAS wsadmin session to actually run.